# Laravel 11 upgrade with Laravel Nova v.26.4 and Symfony/finder 7

Tags: laravel, symfony, laravel-nova

I am trying to do an upgrade on a Laravel project (which composer says requires `symfony/finder 7.0`) and an app that uses `laravel/nova 4.26.4`.

The last problem with composer is:

> laravel/nova 4.26.4 requires symfony/finder ^5.4|^6.0 -> found symfony/finder[v5.4.0, ..., v5.4.35, v6.0.0, ..., v6.4.0] but it conflicts with your root composer.json require (^7.0.0).

Nova itself really cannot be upgraded as the company's perpetual license goes no higher. Any way to get nova to play nice with `symfony/finder 7`?

ETA: Laravel 11 seems to require `symfony/finder 7` (as best as I can tell the first such requirement of the package) - so if there's a chance it'd be happy with a lesser version of finder that'd be great too)

Comment: Remember to not add personal opinions as they are totally irrelevant (in this case) to what issues you are having. Based on what you are saying, if `laravel/nova` requires `^5.6|^6.0`, you know that `^7` is not compatible, and I understand if everything else, even the laravel app, is requiring `^7`. I recommend you to go to the official [Nova documentation bug](https://nova.laravel.com/docs/support.html) help page and it tells you to create an issue on [their github repository](https://github.com/laravel/nova-issues), more than that, I am not sure we can be of help